# Cannot Upload Game to Play Console (64 bit libraries not available)

Tags: android, android-ndk, 64-bit, bundle, cocos2d-x

> Hello, I made a simple game, and Uploaded it to play store. It gives error as "64 bit native libraries required, but the app is 32-bit".

> I also added this lines in build.gradle :

```
       ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

> Also, upon Inspection of the APK, this is what I found (Screenshot) :
> [Screenhot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceZDH.png)

> But still at the time of uploading , I get the Same error :

```
This release is not complaint with 64-bit play requirement.
```

> What should I do, I am a beginner in game dev

Comment: From the screenshot, you clearly don't have any 64-bit libraries. Where does libplayer.so come from?